# Is elt.cloneNode(true) synchronous?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, dom, mutation-observers, clonenode

I need to know if element.cloneNode(true) could be asynchronous with regard to JavaScript. I ran something like this:

```
tempMu = document.createElement("section");
var mu = new MutationObserver(function(mus) {
    console.log("mus", mus);
});
mu.observe(tempMu, {childList:true, subtree:true});
setTimeout(()=>mu.disconnect(), 1000);
tempMu.appendChild(aLargeDiv.cloneNode(true));
```

I got only one mutation callback, but that does not convince me, of course. Do anyone have any knowledge of this?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/161414/discussion-on-question-by-leo-is-elt-clonenodetrue-synchronous).

Comment: @Bergi I do not buy that. See here instead: 2.5.2 Dynamic markup insertion in HTML (https://www.w3.org/TR/2008/WD-html5-20080610/dom.html). I can't see anything about sync/async there (except for document node where they state an event is fired).

Comment: This question seems misdirected. Cloning a node doesn't fire any kind of mutation event. Inserting a new item can trigger mutations, but it is irrelevant whether clone or some other method is used to create that new element. Your code only triggers a single mutation because you only ever perform one mutation, that is it. The fact that you disconnect later doesn't have any way to affect that.

Comment: If your question is if the mutation observer callback runs before `setTimeout`'s callback, that is what you should ask, but about synchronous logic and `cloneNode`.

Comment: @loganfsmyth Aren't you just assuming how it works?

Answer (score 0):

I submitted a request for documentation to Chromium:

795620 - Is cloneNode guaranteed to run synchronously? - chromium - Monorail https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=795620

Comment: I don't see what this has to do with Chromium. If there is or should be documentation on this, it surely belongs in the DOM spec or the JavaScript spec.

Comment: @Alohci It belongs to the W3C spec, of course, but I do not think we are there yet.